# How to calculate number of days from a specified data till today?

Tags: pandas

Hi i have a database something lile this:

**custId   gender  firstdate  fisrtregion  lastdate  buytime**

1. abc         m       yymmdd     xws          yymmdd
2. qwe         f       yymmdd     rty          yymmdd    1
3. dfg         m       yymmdd     rew          yymmdd    1

and i need to find days between last  purchase date till today.
how can i do it.

Comment: i need to find the number of days from the database column lastdate till today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you number of days from the database column lastdate till today

> ```
> nm = date.today()
> df['lastdate'] = df['lastdate'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x),'%Y%m%d'))
> df['days_from_last_buy'] = date.today() - df['lastdate']
> temp = df[['custid','days_from_last_buy']].groupby('custid').agg(max)
> temp.columns = ['last_visit_date'] 
> df.merge(temp,how='left',left_on='custId',right_index=True)
> ```

Comment: i am getting my last date as 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020130216 if my last date is given as 20130216.

Comment: Make sure df['lastdate'] is in string format. After that use this to change into date format. 
datetime.strptime(str(20130216),'%Y%m%d')
I have changed the same in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
print (df)
  custId gender firstdate fisrtregion lastdate buytime
0    abc      m    yymmdd         xws   171014       9
1    qwe      f    yymmdd         rty   171116       1
2    dfg      m    yymmdd         rew   171115       1

#convert to datetimes if necessary
df['lastdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lastdate'], format='%y%m%d')
print (df)
  custId gender firstdate fisrtregion   lastdate buytime
0    abc      m    yymmdd         xws 2017-10-14       9
1    qwe      f    yymmdd         rty 2017-11-16       1
2    dfg      m    yymmdd         rew 2017-11-15       1

#subtract today with last value in column lastdate
d1 = (pd.to_datetime('today') - df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('lastdate')]).days
print (d1)
20

#diference with max datetime
d2 = (pd.to_datetime('today') - df['lastdate'].max()).days
print (d2)
19

#subtract today with column lastdate and convert timedeltas to days
df['new'] = (pd.to_datetime('today') - df['lastdate']).dt.days
print (df)
  custId gender firstdate fisrtregion   lastdate buytime  new
0    abc      m    yymmdd         xws 2017-10-14       9   52
1    qwe      f    yymmdd         rty 2017-11-16       1   19
2    dfg      m    yymmdd         rew 2017-11-15       1   20
```

Comment: df['lastdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['lastdate'], format='%y%m%d')
print (df)   : using the following command as suggested by you i am not getting the desired output as you have mentioned   . i am getting my last date as 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020130216 if my last date is given as 20130216.

Comment: It depends of your real data, there is some error? Or what is wrong? Can you explain more?

Comment: i am getting my last date as 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020130216 if my last date is given as 20130216. it is not getting converted to 2013-02-16 as suggested by you.

Comment: I see it, need change `format='%y%m%d')` to `format='%Y%m%d')`, because format of year is `YYYY` not `YY`

Comment: still getting the same output

Comment: my lastdate type is datetime64[ns]. does this needs to be converted to some other type before using the format of %y%m%d as suggested by you.

Comment: Yes, sure, converting should me omitted.